# AS3 - I'm trying to play the sound file through XML playlist but it doesn't seem to be working

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, audio

I'm trying to play the sound file through XML playlist but it doesn't seem to be working.
I am getting this: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. Any idea why? Help Appreciated Very Much.

```
var soundURL:URLRequest;
var mySound:Sound = new Sound (); 
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var playing:Boolean = true;
var resumeTime:Number = 0;
var myCurrentSong:Number = 0;
var currentSong:int = 0;
var loadedXML:XML

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("playList.xml");
myXMLLoader.load(myURL);

myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML(e:Event):void {
loadedXML = XML(e.target.data);
soundURL = new URLRequest(loadedXML.songFile[currentSong].@songURL); 
mySound = new Sound(soundURL);
}

btnPlayPause.buttonMode = true;
btnStop.buttonMode = true;
btnNext.buttonMode = true;

btnPlayPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);

function playSound(m:MouseEvent){
if (playing==true)
{
btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPause");
mySound.load(myURL);
mySoundChannel = mySound.play(resumeTime);
playing = false;
}
else
{
btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPlay");
resumeTime = mySoundChannel.position;
mySoundChannel.stop();
playing = true;
  }
}

function stopSound(f:MouseEvent):void
{
mySoundChannel.stop();
}
```

Comment: Well it's obvious by the error that there is a stream error, which means that the file cannot be loaded. Trace out the url to see what's going on.

Comment: Beak the problem into bits: loading the data, parsing data (correctly), using the data (playback a sound). You're stuck at one and the IOErrorEvent is kind of like a 404 error in the browser, flash player can't find the xml at the path you've given it. Make sure playlist.xml is in the same folder as the .swf file and try again.

Comment: The xml files are in the same folder as my .swf file. And i've thoroughly checked the spellings too, there's no typo even.

Comment: So the error occurs when you load XML or when you load the sound file?

Comment: Yes, when i am trying to play the sound file.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but for a slight problem in setting up your track URL..

if your `XML` file looks something like this

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<MP3s>

    <songFile>


        <songURL> Apakalypse_Exist.mp3 </songURL>   


    </songFile>

</MP3s>
```

then the code should work. Look at the last line of the `function processXML`

```
var soundURL:URLRequest;
var mySound:Sound = new Sound (); 
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var playing:Boolean = true;
var resumeTime:Number = 0;
var myCurrentSong:Number = 0;
var currentSong:int = 0;
var loadedXML:XML;

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("playList.xml");

////Setup... 
btnPlayPause.buttonMode = true;
btnStop.buttonMode = true;
btnNext.buttonMode = true;

btnPlayPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);

myXMLLoader.load (myURL);
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);


//// Functions...
function processXML (e:Event):void 
{
    loadedXML = XML(e.target.data);
    //trace("loaded XML" + loadedXML); //for test only

    //soundURL = new URLRequest(loadedXML.songFile[currentSong].@songURL); 
    //mySound = new Sound(soundURL);

    mySound = new Sound(new URLRequest(loadedXML.songFile[currentSong].songURL));
}

function playSound (m:MouseEvent)
{
    if (playing==true)
    {
        btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPause");
        //mySound.load(myURL);
        mySoundChannel = mySound.play(resumeTime);
        playing = false;
    }
    else
    {
        btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPlay");
        resumeTime = mySoundChannel.position;
        mySoundChannel.stop();
        playing = true;
    }
}

function stopSound (f:MouseEvent):void
{
    mySoundChannel.stop();
}
```